# Annihilator of a submodule of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ a unitary
$R$-module. I am looking for some conditions on $M $, such that for every ideal $I$ of $R$ with $ann_R (M)\subseteq I$, we can construct a
submodule $N$ of $M$ such that $ann_R(N)\subseteq
I\subseteq\sqrt{ann_R(N)}$.

Comment: n/m, i had an objection, but when I originally began the thought I forgot that we had freedom with $N$.

Comment: What kind of conditions are you looking for? Some condition is too vague.

Comment: Any condition is well come. can you state some of them?  thanks for any help.

Comment: What motivates the question, out of curiosity? I have thought about this sort of thing in the past, and I'm interested in where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a sufficient condition (not necessary). I will assume that $R$ is Noetherian, since I am always uncomfortable with non-Noetherian rings. Also we may always go modulo the annihilator of $M$ and thus assume it is zero, since only $R/\mathrm{ann}\,M$ comes into play. So, now $I$ is any ideal.

First, let me fix some notation. For any prime ideal $P$ of $R$, let $E(P)$ denote the injective hull of $R/P$. Let $E=\oplus_{P\in\mathrm{Spec}\, A} E(P)$. Then any module which contains $E$ as a submodule will satisfy your requirement. The proof essentially will use basic properties of $E(P)$ and if you are unsure, I could give you some hints.

Let me also show that this is not necessary. Take $(R,\pi)$ to be a dvr and let $M=\oplus_n R/\pi^n$.